# How to fix undefined issue on d3 tooltip?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to display some relevant data when a user hovers over one of the circle marks on the scatterplot.

[image]

but that is not working. I have been searching for a while and I tried using the browser tooltip which works but it gives a lag and I don't want to depend on it. Here is my data:

[image]

at the moment, I create a div in the same div I added my svg in and then I append the text only when the user hovers. I want to display the data from the all_title column. my js code:

```
var div = d3.select("#scatter")
                        .append("div")
                        .attr("class", "tooltip")
                        .style("opacity", 0);

        var svg_scatter= d3.select("#scatter")
                                .append("svg")
                                .attr('id', 'scatter_plot')
                                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                                .append("g")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); 

svg_scatter.append('g')
                .attr("id", "circles")                   
                .attr("clip-path", "url(#chart-area)")  
                .selectAll("circle")
                .data(Dialogue_dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function (d) { return xScale(d.percentage); } )
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d.value); })
                .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          
                        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cx"));
                        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cy"));
                
                   
                        svg_scatter.append("text")
                                .attr("id", "tooltip")
                                .attr("x", xPosition)
                                .attr("y", yPosition)
                                .text( "list of movies "+d.all_title);

                        })
                .on("mouseout", function() {

                        //Remove the tooltip
                        d3.select("#tooltip").remove();
                
                });
```

my HTML:

```
<div id = "scatter"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `d3 v6`, the [event listener signature](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_on) is as follow:

```js
listener(event, datum)
```

So you want to write,

```
            .on("mouseover", function(event, d) {
      
                    var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cx"));
                    var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cy"));
            
               
                    svg_scatter.append("text")
                            .attr("id", "tooltip")
                            .attr("x", xPosition)
                            .attr("y", yPosition)
                            .text( "list of movies "+d.all_title);

                    })
```